# Display the value on click of check box in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, checkbox

I have an array of 10 checkboxes. onclick of checkbox i want to get the value of that particular checkbox. That I am able to achieve using my code.When I click in serial order it is working fine. When I click on checkbox 5 after clicking on checkbox 7 the value of checkbox 5 ie..5 is getting added befor 7. I dont want in that order. I want the values to displayed in whatever order I click. My js file is as follows

```
var selected = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){

checkBoxTest();

}); 
function checkBoxTest() {
    alert("checkbox test");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        $("#catalog_table").append('<tr><td>Checkbox<input type="checkbox"  name ="chkbox"  value="' +i+' "/><td></tr>');
        test();
    } 

}

function test() {
    $('#catalog_table input:checkbox').change(function() {
    var emails = [];
    $('#catalog_table input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
     emails.push($(this).val());
    });
    var textField = document.getElementById("root");
      textField.value = emails;
    });

}
```

My HTML code is something like this

```
<table id="catalog_table"> </table>
<textarea  id="root"></textarea>
```

Can any one please tell me how to do this?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FU7uV/)

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FU7uV/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its messy, but it works:
http://jsfiddle.net/za7m8/1/

```
var selected = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
        // check if we are adding, or removing a selected item
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            selected.push($(this).val());
        } else {
            for(var i = 0; i<selected.length;i++) {
                if (selected[i] == $(this).val()) {
                    // remove the item from the array
                    selected.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // output selected
        var output = "";
        for (var o = 0; o<selected.length; o++) {
            if (output.length) {
                output += ", " + selected[o];
            } else {
                output += selected[o];
            }
        }
        $("#root").val(output);
    });
});
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this for a large collection of checkboxes, the fact it iterates over selected items could make it quite slow in older browsers if you had 100+ selected checkbox's

Comment: Hi I am getting values multiple when implementing this logic please have a look at my code [updatedCode](http://jsfiddle.net/FU7uV/5/)

Comment: You are calling test() in a loop which sets up the event listener. This is creating multiple event listeners so each time you are clicking a checkbox it runs multiple times

Comment: How can I write if I have test() method in loop inorder to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear up your code a bit, like this:

I assume that unchecking removes the value from the array, and checking adds.

```
var selected = new Array(); // What for is this here ?

$(document).ready(function () {    
    checkBoxTest();    
});

function checkBoxTest() {

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        $("#catalog_table").append('<tr><td>Checkbox<input type="checkbox"  name ="chkbox"  value="' + i + ' "/><td></tr>');
    }
    test();
}

function test() {
    var emails = [],
        textField = document.getElementById("root");

    $('#catalog_table input:checkbox').change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

        // if you don't want removal of values on `uncheck`, comment out everything below excluding `emails.push(val)` and the last line

        if(this.checked){    // if checked
            emails.push(val); // add it
        }else{  
            emails.splice(emails.indexOf(val), 1); // remove it if not checked
        }

        textField.value = emails; // set the value
    });
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/FU7uV/4/)

Comment: your logic is little buggy

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Please explain how. Thanks.

Comment: you are only pushing, if checkbox already checked and unchecked you are not handling it

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I was waiting for the response from OP. There might be a possibility that he didn't want so. But, now, I have added that facility too.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to change your javascript like this.

```
var selected = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){

checkBoxTest();

}); 
function checkBoxTest() {
    alert("checkbox test");
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        $("#catalog_table").append('<tr><td>Checkbox<input type="checkbox"  name ="chkbox"  value="' +i+' "/><td></tr>');
        test();
    } 
}

var emails = [];
function test() {
    $('#catalog_table input:checkbox').change(function() {
    if (this.checked)
    {
        if ( emails.indexOf( $(this).val() ) === -1 )
        {
            emails.push($(this).val());
        }            
    } else
    {
        if ( emails.indexOf( $(this).val() ) !== -1 )
        {
            var index = emails.indexOf( $(this).val() );
            emails.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }

    var textField = document.getElementById("root");
    textField.value = emails;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys